# Saving tweets to JSON file in Python 3.6

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tweepy

I'm using the tweepy library to download tweets of certain users. I want to save these tweets into a JSON file but im getting the following error:

> File "", line 63, in getTweetsList
>       json.dump(status._json,file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json__init__.py", line 180, in
>   dump
>
> fp.write(chunk)
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Here is the code:

```
def getTweetsList(self, screen_name):
    # Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method
    # initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  

    # make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = self.api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

    # save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    # save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    # keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:  
        # all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = self.api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

        # save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        # update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print("...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets)))

    print("Total tweets downloaded %s" % (len(alltweets)))
    file = open('tweet.json', 'wb') 
    print("Writing tweet objects to JSON please wait...")
    for status in alltweets:
        json.dump(status._json,file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)
    return alltweets
```

I looked everywhere for an answer, but none of the solutions worked for me. I think it might have something to do with Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the file in binary mode.  The error indicates it wants a bytes object (binary data) due to this.  Tweets are text (Unicode strings).  Use text mode and declare an encoding, e.g.:

```
with open('tweet.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
    json.dump(status._json, file, ...)
```

Note that using a `with` statement ensures the file gets closed.

Comment: Thank you it worked! I want to append to the file though, how can i do that?

Comment: @CharbelHanna Use 'a' instead of 'w'.

Answer (score 1):

- Change the line `json.dump(status._json,file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)` to `json.dumps(status._json,file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)`
- Use `json.dumps`
- `json.dumps` serializes the object to a JSON formatted string
- "dumps" means "dump string"

Comment: i got this error:

TypeError: dumps() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 2 keyword-only arguments) were given